# Is it possible track Google CSE?

Tags: google

I have many Google Custom Search engines that I need to track. In other words, I need to know the search terms of the users. Otherwise, it is hard to improve the engines. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Google Analytics, you could enable "Site Search":

[Google Help : How do I set up Site Search for my profile?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75817)

---

**Edit:**

Here is a tutorial: 
[**Know What Your Customers Want: Analyze Internal Search Data With Google Analytics**](http://www.conversationmarketing.com/2007/07/analyze_internal_search_data_w.htm#ixzz0Jf69pWyF&D)

On Step 6 it's important that you enter this exact formula into the Field A -> Extract A field:

```
q=([^&]*)&sa=Search.
```

[image: Screenshot Google Analytics]
<sub>(source: [conversationmarketing.com](http://www.conversationmarketing.com/200707310742-1-tm.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I did it, but I have a google CSE in iFrame and a standard engine from Google Sites. It does not track the Google CSE in iFrame, but it tracks the standard engine in Google Sites. I have no idea how to  track the Google CSE.

Answer (score 0):

If the results page of your Google CSE is on your site, you can just analyze your access logs to pull the search terms out.  You should see URLs like `http://yoursite.com/cseresults.html?q=keywords`.